# The DELETE & PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD,POST

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I need your help guys on this, my app can't delete neither can it Update. it keeps on popping these errors on my edit and Delete Buttons;

```
(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.



(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

this is my route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('/device', 'DeviceController');
});
```

this is my edit blade

```
<form action="/device" method="POST" id="editForm">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}

   <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
   <label>Serial Number</label>
     <input type="text" name="Serial_No" id="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Serial number">
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Data</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
   <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-middle">Clear</button>
</form>
```

This is my delete blade

```
     <form action="/device" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}

             <div class="form-row">
             <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" >
             <P>Are You Sure!.. You want to delete this Device?</P>
             </div>

       <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" >YES! DELETE DEVICE</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-dismiss="modal" >CANCEL</button>

      </form>
```

This is my controller for delete

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $devices = Device::find($id);
        $devices -> delete();
        return Redirect::back() -> with('success','Data Deleted Successfully');
    }
```

This is my script that deletes

```
<script>
//Start Delete Record

        table.on('click', '.delete', function () {

        $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if ($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
          $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
        }

        var data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#deleteForm').attr('action', '/laptops/'+data[0]);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        });
        //End Delete Record

      });
</script>
```

Comment: `<form>` inside `<form>` - don't do it. Make them separate forms. (And close the second form)

Comment: thanks but you didn't understand what my question was

Comment: There's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers) on resource controllers and the "_Actions Handled By Resource Controller_": your `/device` route can only be accessed via GET/POST, you are missing the actual device (object) in your actions

Comment: Change `action="/device"` to `action="{{ route(device.add, [$device->id]) }}"` and for delete `action="{{ route(device.destroy, [$device->id]) }}"`

Comment: that didn't workout

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct actions

your update form should look like this instead

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="editForm">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}

   <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
   <label>Serial Number</label>
     <input type="text" name="Serial_No" id="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Serial number">
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Data</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
   <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-middle">Clear</button>
</form>
```

your delete form should look like this instead.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{method_field('DELETE')}}

  <div class="form-row">
    <p>Are You Sure!.. You want to delete this Device?</p>
  </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit">YES! DELETE DEVICE</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-dismiss="modal">
    CANCEL
  </button>
</form>
```

your script should look like this (change 'laptops/' to 'device/')

```
table.on('click', '.delete', function () {
    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    if ($($tr).hasClass('child')) {
          $tr = $tr.prev('.parent');
        }

        var data = table.row($tr).data();
        console.log(data);

        $('#deleteForm').attr('action', '/device/'+data[0]);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        });
```

Also as an opinion you could pluralize your resource route instead of the singular approach. i.e `/devices` instead of `/device`
so in your web.php routes file you have:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:Admin']], function () {
    Route::resource('/devices', 'DeviceController');
});
```

That way you have a more friendly route list like:

```
GET - /devices
GET - /devices/create
POST - /devices/update
GET - /devices/{device}
GET - /devices/{device}/edit
PUT/PATCH - /devices/{device}
DELETE - /devices/{device}
```

All these can be viewed in your cli using `php artisan route:list`

Comment: i have this error now;        Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: have done it in all possible ways but can't figure out whats bringing the same errors over and over again, i should invite you to my project and you see it

Comment: @MATOVUJOELCLINTON Alright, if it's on GitHub, you can find me here http://github.com/aeadedoyin

Comment: hello @adedoyin-akande i want to invite you and you help me out with my issue , i even tried to make a copy of my project to Laravel 7x but still i fell in the same error with means the issue is in the UI or script or something related to that

Comment: Here is my Twitter handle https://twitter.com/aeadedoyin
You can send me a DM